# How to import a list of phrases to PhraseExpress?

Tags: import, phraseexpress

I'm using PhraseExpress v11 and I would like to import a list of 100+ phrases to a folder in the **Local Phrase File**.
My phrases are currently in a .txt file, every word is in a new line.
All phrases should get the same settings. Example:

```
Description = Phrase (e.g. StackOverflow)
Phrase Content = Phrase (e.g. StackOverflow)
Postfix = SmartComplete
```

Is there a way to import them as a list?

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier, put each phrase in one line and separate phrase description by commas and save it with the file extension .csv ("comma separated values").

Then click "File" » "Import" and select CSV files.

You can enable "SmartComplete" later in the editor. You don't need to import those as SmartComplete takes the phrase description as the trigger.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some of my phrases contain a comma (e.g.; hello, how are you doing?) That seems to break the .csv import. How to escape them?